# Selenium RC 403 Error - Forbidden for proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to run Selenium RC 1.0.3 using Java 6, JUnit 4, and Eclipse on Snow Leopard.

Here is my test class, from the Selenium docs:

```
public class TestCase extends SeleneseTestCase {

  @Before
  public void before() throws Exception {
    setUp("http://www.google.com/", "*firefox");
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.type("q", "selenium rc");
    selenium.click("btnG");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Advanced search"));
  }
}
```

I receive the following error, which occurs at the time that `selenium.open()` is called:

```
11:16:59.916 INFO - Got result: 
XHR ERROR: URL = http://localhost:4444/ Response_Code = 403 
Error_Message = Forbidden+for+Proxy on session a8cf1e0bd5ed42c5a4df0c25ec5f5286
```

I've tried (finding various suggestions on the web) replacing `*firefox` with `*chrome` or `*firefox`, replacing `http` with `https` and adding `selenium.start()`, but none have helped, or even changed the behavior.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**  The selenium-server is running, and the local firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's a solution, without any understanding:  If the `@Before` method is removed, and the call to `setUp()` is moved into the `@Test` method, then it works:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
  setUp("http://www.google.com/", "*chrome");
  selenium.open("/");
  selenium.type("q", "selenium rc");
  selenium.click("btnG");
  selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
  assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Advanced search"));
}
```

But here is a better solution, based on understanding:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase;

public class TestCase extends SeleneseTestCase {

  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    setUp("http://www.google.com/", "*firefox");
  }

  public void testAuto() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.type("q", "selenium rc");
    selenium.click("btnG");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Advanced search"));
  }
}
```

It turns out that `SeleneseTestCase` extends `TestCase` from JUnit 3.  I had upgraded the documentation example to JUnit 4 without thinking about what problems may be caused.

Comment: I don't know if it's a cut and paste error or not, but according to the JUnit4 docs, your before method should be static, and after finding the source for SeleneseTestCase, it looks like the setup method is trying to manipulate instance data, which it couldn't get to. Not sure why that isn't throwing an error.

Comment: If you run your test in TestNG, it doesn't have the same requirements for static methods.

Comment: Are you thinking of the `@BeforeClass` annotation?  Otherwise, give me the link, I use `@Before` for non-static methods frequently.

Comment: You are right, my eyes just kind of skipped over the "non static" on the @Before. Sorry. Are you able to just get right through if just open the URL in the browser otherwise?

Comment: Yes.  I can do that, or use either of the solutions posted here.